# angular2 http:post throwing error

Tags: http, post, angular

I'm working on a simple CRUD application in angular2, and I'm having trouble posting to a backend server.  My code for the class is as follows

```
export class PersonForm {
  data:Object;
  loading: boolean;
  personForm: ControlGroup;
  http:Http;
  constructor(personFormBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.personForm = personFormBuilder.group({
      'name': [],
      'age': []
    });
  }

  onSubmit(value:any) : void {
    console.log('you submitted these values: ', value);
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/people/create",JSON.stringify(value))
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        this.loading = true;
  });

 }

}
```

The above is causing the following error in my console.  I'm not sure what is undefined as I'm following every example I've found exactly:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "ngSubmit"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'this.http.post')
```

Here is my imports just in case I'm missing a component

```
import {Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {ControlGroup} from "angular2/common";
```

Comment: You have to inject Http in your constructor.

Comment: `Http` should be imported there & your class constructor should define a new object from it.. otherwise it should be there in your parent component atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the `http` object in the component constructor:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class PersonForm {
  data:Object;
  loading: boolean;
  personForm: ControlGroup;
  http:Http;

  constructor(private http: Http, personFormBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: can't be the case OP have `Http` dependency injected in parent component?

Comment: @Pankaj I can't see a parent component in the question ;-) I guess `PersonForm` is a component. An `Http` object should be provided by injection and not as parameter of a component...

Comment: Make sense, just have a thought about it :) +1